# Splitting a string by spaces without space-splitting elements in double-quotes

Tags: python, strings, python-3.x

I need to split a command like:

```
r'  "C:\Program Files (x86)\myeditor" "$FILEPATH" -n$LINENO "c:\Program Files" -f$FILENAME -aArg2'`
```

into:

```
['"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\myeditor"',
 '"$FILEPATH"',
 '-n$LINENO',
 '"c:\\Program Files"',
 '-f$FILENAME',
 '-aArg2']
```

That is, I want to split by spaces, but avoid splitting the elements in double-quotes.

I have this code:

```
import re

s = r'  "C:\Program Files (x86)\myeditor" "$FILEPATH" -n$LINENO "c:\Program Files" -f$FILENAME -aArg2'

start = end = 0
split = []

for elem in re.findall('".*?"', s):
    end = s.find(elem)
    split.append(s[start:end])
    split.append(elem)
    start = end + len(elem)

split.extend(s[start:].split())
split = [elem.strip() for elem in split]
split = list(filter(None, split))
```

It works, but I'm wondering if there's some more elegant/shorter/more readable way to do that in Python(3) ?

Comment: Already answered: https://stackoverflow.com/q/366202/823470

Comment: @tar That answer is on Java and some complex regexes. I think that `shlex` + copying doublequotes is a more pythonic and sensible approach, as it follows line of thinking "use the standard library if it does the job".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The best way to do what you want with the standard library would be [shlex.split()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.split):

```
>>> import shlex
>>> s = r'  "C:\Program Files (x86)\myeditor" "$FILEPATH" -n$LINENO "c:\Program Files" -f$FILENAME -aArg2'
>>> shlex.split(s)
['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\myeditor', '$FILEPATH', '-n$LINENO', 'c:\\Program Files', '-f$FILENAME', '-aArg2']
```

Note that the quotes are not retained.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a different regex:

```
import re

s = r'  "C:\Program Files (x86)\myeditor" "$FILEPATH" -n$LINENO "c:\Program Files" -f$FILENAME -aArg2'

pattern = re.compile(r"((\"[^\"]+\")|(-[^\s]+))")

for m in re.finditer(pattern, s):
    print(m.group(0))
```

This regex will match either an item enclosed by double quotes (`"`) or an item prepended with a dash (`-`).

However this might be harder to read/grasp and I'm also not sure if this is considered *pythonic* as it's the Perl way of doing things so take this with a grain of salt.